# Scala REPL: How to find function type?

Tags: function, scala, types, read-eval-print-loop

In Scala REPL one can find value types:

```
    scala> val x = 1
    x: Int = 1

    scala> :t x
    Int
```

Yet Scala REPL does not show the type information for functions:

```
    scala> def inc(x:Int) = x + 1
    inc: (x: Int)Int

scala> :t inc
<console>:9: error: missing arguments for method inc;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
       inc
       ^
<console>:9: error: missing arguments for method inc;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
          inc
          ^
```

How to find function type in Scala REPL ?

Comment: How about doing what it says in the error message?

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15583551/type-information-in-the-scala-repl)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Following the suggestion will work pretty well:

```
:t inc _
Int => Int
```

To give a bit more detail, the reason this is necessary is that Scala maintains a distinction between 'methods', which have native support in the JVM but which are not first class, and 'functions', which are treated as instances of `FunctionX` and seen as objects by the JVM. The use of the trailing underscore converts the former to the latter.

Comment: Thanks! Why then I can not do: `:t scala.collection.immutable.List.type.foldLeft _` and also I can not do `:t java.Lang.String.split _` ?

Comment: Those are both class methods, and you can only partially apply (i.e. convert to a `Function` object) an instance method. Create a particular instance of a `List`, say, and you'll be able to inspect the type of its `foldLeft` method.

Answer (score 4):

You can write the name of the method and press tab.

```
Stream.fill<tab>
```

gives you:

```
def fill[A](n1: Int,n2: Int,n3: Int)(elem: => A): 
scala.collection.immutable.Stream[scala.collection.immutable.Stream[scala.collection.immutable.Stream[A]]]
def fill[A](n1: Int,n2: Int,n3: Int,n4: Int)(elem: => A): scala.collection.immutable.Stream[scala.collection.immutable.Stream[scala.collection.immutable.Stream[scala.collection.immutable.Stream[A]]]]
def fill[A](n1: Int,n2: Int)(elem: => A): scala.collection.immutable.Stream[scala.collection.immutable.Stream[A]]
def fill[A](n1: Int,n2: Int,n3: Int,n4: Int,n5: Int)(elem: => A): scala.collection.immutable.Stream[scala.collection.immutable.Stream[scala.collection.immutable.Stream[scala.collection.immutable.Stream[scala.collection.immutable.Stream[A]]]]]
override def fill[A](n: Int)(elem: => A): scala.collection.immutable.Stream[A]
```