# Type Mismatch in scala, Array[Int] and Array[Option[Int]]

Tags: arrays, scala, bigdata

First, I am new to Scala, So apologies if the following question is too simple.

I have written the following code to the find the values of the keys that I supply in an array from the map.

```
def stringToCountMap(inputArray: Array[String], inputMap:Map[String,Int]) : Array[Int] = {
    return inputArray.map(x => inputMap.get(x))
}
```

I got the following error,

```
type mismatch;
 found   : Array[Option[Int]]
 required: Array[Int]
 return inputArray.map(x => inputMap.get(x))
```

Question:
1) Can anyone explain what is Option[Int]? 
2) What is my mistake here ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note you can [examine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15583552/90527) the type of an expression in the Scala REPL using `:t` (or `:type`, if you prefer being verbose), which you can use to examine a [function's type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15611669/90527): `:t inputMap.get _` (after defining a suitable `inputMap`).

Comment: I will try this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[`Option`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html) is Scala's [option type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_type) (also called a [nullable type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nullable_type)). It represents a case where the value may not exist.

Consider a map that doesn't contain a requested key. How would you handle a request for the key? One option is to result in an error, such as by throwing an exception. Another is to return a special value that indicates there is no value. [`Map.get`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Map.html#get(key:K):Option[V]) does the latter, using `Option` as the special type and `None` as the value. This means the return type of `Map.get` isn't the value type of the map (`Int`), but `Option` applied to the value type (`Option[Int]`).

To correct the type declaration, change the return type:

```
def stringToCountMap(inputArray: Array[String], inputMap:Map[String,Int]) : Array[Option[Int]] = {
    inputArray.map(x => inputMap.get(x))
}
```

You can leave out the return type of `stringToCountMap` and let type inference handle it:

```
def stringToCountMap(inputArray: Array[String], inputMap:Map[String,Int]) = {
    inputArray.map(x => inputMap.get(x))
}
```

As a consequence, missing keys from the input map get carried through:

```
scala> stringToCountMap(Array("a", "def"), Map("a" -> 1, "bc" -> 2))
res0: Array[Option[Int]] = Array(Some(1), None)
```

Answer (score 1):

`Option[T]` is a wrapper around a value of type `T`. Its purpose is to prevent `NullPointerException`, that you might know from Java. A value of type `Option[T]` might either be `None`, which, as the name implies is an object that represents nothing, or it might be `Some(x: T)`, which represents an existing value.

`inputMap(x)` returns an `Option[Int]`, since you have no guarantee that the `x` key exists in `inputMap`. If it does, it returns `Some(value: Int)`, else it returns `None`.

Calling `stringToCountMap(Array("a", "b", "c"), Map("a" -> 1, "c" -> 2))` results in `Array(Some(1), None, Some(2))`

If you want an `Array[Int]` instead, you might do something like `inputArray.map(x => inputMap.getOrElse(x, 0)).get`. The `getOrElse` method has two parameters, where the first one is the key, and the second one is the default value. `inputArray.map(x => inputMap.get(x).getOrElse(0))` has the same effect, since calling `getOrElse(value)` on an `Option` either unwraps the `Some` object, or returns the default value.

Now, `stringToCountMap(Array("a", "b", "c"), Map("a" -> 1, "c" -> 2))` results in `Array(1, 0, 2)`.

You might also want to omit the keys missing in the input array. In that case, you might do `inputArray.flatMap(x => inputMap.get(x))`. `flatMap` is a function similar to `map`, but it returns strictly, as the name implies, flat collections. For example, calling `flatMap(x => x)` on an `Array[Array[Int]]` would return an `Array` of all the values in the 2D array in a single row.
Here, `Option` is a collection, as well. If it is of type `Some`, it contains a single value, if it is `None`, it is an empty collection. Thus, in the resulting array you would only have the values of the keys present in the map, and the keys not present in the map are skipped.

Now, `stringToCountMap(Array("a", "b", "c"), Map("a" -> 1, "c" -> 2))` results in `Array(1, 2)`.

Comment: I understood the concept. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, there is no need to use 'return' in scala to return any value.

```
def stringToCountMap(inputArray: Array[String], inputMap:Map[String,Int])  = {
     inputArray.map(x => inputMap.get(x))
}
```

When you get the value of key from Map, It returns result in Option. 
For example:

```
scala> val map  = Map(1-> "a",2 -> "b")
map: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,String] = Map(1 -> a, 2 -> b)

scala> map.get(1)
res0: Option[String] = Some(a)

scala> map.get(3)
res1: Option[String] = None
```

When you try to get the value of key, which does not exist. In java, you have encountered with NullPointerException. So when there is no value, it returns None to avoid exception.
For more info [refer](http://blog.danielwellman.com/2008/03/using-scalas-op.html) 
In your method, you have given return type as Array[Int] but function returns Array[Option[Int]] that's why it throws compilation error.

Comment: On SO, the best way to show thanks is to [vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote).